# Need an audio player that loops forever

Tags: audio, mp3-player

For a prototype, I need to use a MP3 player that meet these requirements:

- Loops a .mp3 file forever when turned on
- Can be plugged into a wall (no need to replace batteries)
- Have a 3.5mm or 6.35mm audio output
- If possible starts playing as soon as I plug it into the wall i.e no need to press the play button, select a playlist to play, etc

I thought of purchasing one of these old MP3 devices:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But I'm not sure it meets all of the above conditions

EDIT: **Reason we need this:** We have a device that streams audio to a hearing aid. This device shutsdown in 5 minutes if there is no audio i.e muted. But we have a specific case where we need it to be on forever, so we thought of a mp3 player that loops an audio file of 4m30s with a little beep at the end just to stimulate the streamer to stay on

Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you using this player for exactly? I understand you want to play a song, but where/why is it being installed?

Comment: Arduino Uno / ATMEGA328P with an MP3 player module perhaps

Comment: @JMY1000 We have a device that streams audio to a hearing aid. This device shutsdown in 5 minutes if there is no audio i.e muted. But we have a specific case where we need it to be on forever, so we thought of a mp3 player that loops an audio file of 4m30s with a little beep at the end just to stimulate the streamer to stay on.

Comment: @towe Good idea! I loop the audio through code, it starts playing as soon as it is plugged in and the MP3 player module goes to a 3.5mm output module. Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Don't think so. The normal breadboards would probably be too wonky for audio, so you'd have to use a strip board and solder it, but it should work fine.

Comment: If you’re comfortable with the SBC route, there are other boards with audio onboard like the Pi.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what device do you use to stream the audio to the hearing aids? It may be that there is a solution that does not involve external devices feeding audio into it, which will cause anyone with a hearing aid to hear a beep every 5 minutes. Sorry if I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @JoelWinterton the Device is called ReSound TV Streamer by the danish company ReSound. It automatically turns off every 5 minutes when there's no audio feed. We actually want to use the hearing aids as a communicator instead of sound amplifier. A professional in-ear communicator is actually very expensive and a Hearing Aid, specifically ReSound's, has very useful tools for our needs as wells.

Comment: The easiest custom solution I've found is the Adafruit Music Maker FeatherWing attached to an Adafruit Feather 32u4 Basic Proto, which has LiPO battery connector and charger. You even have a full project demo: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2771